# How does the GHC garbage collector / runtime know that it can create an array `inplace'

Tags: haskell, runtime, ghc

For example

```
main = do
  let ls = [0..10000000]
  print ls
```

This will create the array 'inplace', using O(1) memory.

The following edit causes the program to run out of memory while executing.

```
main = do
  let ls = [0..10000000]
  print ls
  print ls
```

`ls` in this case must be kept in memory to be printed again. It would actually be heaps more memory efficient to recalculate the array again 'inplace' than to try to keep this in place. That's an aside though. My real question is "how and when does GHC communicate to the runtime system that `ls` can be destroyed while it's created in O(1) time?" I understand that liveness analysis can find this information, I'm just wondering where the information is used. Is it the garbage collector that is passed this info? Is it somehow compiled away? (If I look at the compiled core from GHC then both examples use `eftInt`, so if it's a compiler artifact then it must happen at a deeper level).

edit: My question was more about finding where this optimization took place. I thought maybe it was in the GC, which was fed some information from some liveness check in the compilation step. Due to the answers so far I'm probably wrong. This is most likely then happening at some lower level before core, so cmm perhaps?

edit2: Most of the answers here assume that the GC knows that `ls` is no longer referenced in the first example, and that it is referenced again in the second example. I know the basics of GC and I know that arrays are linked lists, etc. My question is exactly *HOW* the GC knows this. The answer could probably be only (a) it is getting extra information from the compiler, or (b) it doesn't need to know this, that this information is handled 100% by the compiler

Comment: I think it is not the Garbage Collector but the Haskell GHC compiler which know that. And GHC is rumored to use very clever compilation techniques. BTW, GHC is free software, and is rumored to have very nice forums and lists.

Comment: There's a forum for GHC?

Comment: Yes, see https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/MailingListsAndIRC

Comment: I know of the list and the IRC channel, but didn't know of any forum. And I guess there isn't one.

Comment: Sometimes GHC is able to prevent intermediate data structures like lists cells to be created. This is done as an optimization step by the compiler, not by the GC at run time. The techniques involved are typically referred to as deforestation or fusion.

Comment: Arrays are not linked lists. Lists are linked lists. `[1,2,3]` is not an array. For arrays, look in the `array` and especially `vector` packages.

Comment: Fair point, I mistyped that. I meant lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This explanation is probably a lie, especially because I'm making it up as I go, but that shouldn't be a problem.

The essential mistake you're making is assuming that a value is live if a variable bound to it is in scope in a live expression. This is simply wrong. A value bound to a variable is only live as a result if it is actually *mentioned in* a live expression.

The job of the runtime is very simple

1. Execute the expression bound to `main`.
2. There is no 2.

We can think of this execution as involving a couple different steps that repeat over and over:

1. Figure out what to do now.
2. Figure out what to do next.

So we start with some `main` expression. From the start, the "root set" for GC consists of those names that are used in that `main` expression, *not* the things that are in *scope* in that expression. If I write

```
foo = "Hi!"
main = print "Bye!"
```

then since `foo` is not mentioned in `main`, it is not in the root set at the beginning, and since it is not even mentioned indirectly by anything mentioned by `main`, it is dead right from the start.

Now suppose we take a more interesting example:

```
foo = "Hi!"
bar = "Bye!"
main = print foo >> print bar
```

Now `foo` is mentioned in `main`, so it starts out live. We evaluate `main` to weak head normal form to find out what to do, and we get, approximately,

```
(primitive operation that prints out "Hi!") >> print bar
```

Note that `foo` is no longer mentioned, so it is dead!

Now we execute that primitive operation, printing "Hi!", and our "to do list" is reduced to

```
print bar
```

Now we evaluate that to WHNF, and get, roughly,

```
(primitive operation to print "Bye!")
```

Now `bar` is dead. We print "Bye!" and exit.

---

Consider, now, the first program you described:

```
main = do
  let ls = [0..10000000]
  print ls
```

This desugars to

```
main =
  let ls = [0..10000000]
  in print ls
```

This is where we start. The "root set" at the beginning is everything mentioned in the `in` clause of the expression. So we conceptually have `ls` and `print` to start out. Now we can imagine that `print`, specialized to `[Integer]`, looks something vaguely like the following (this is greatly simplified, and will print out the list differently, but that really doesn't matter).

```
print xs = case xs of
  [] -> return ()
  (y:ys) = printInteger y >> print ys
```

So when we start executing `main` (What do we do now? What will we do afterwards?), we are trying to calculate `print ls`. To do this, we pattern match on the first constructor of `ls`, which forces `ls` to be evaluated to WHNF. We find the second pattern, `y:ys`, matches, so we replace `print ls` with `print Integer y >> print ys`, where `y` points to the first element of `ls` and `ys` points to the thunk representing the second list constructor of `ls`. But note that `ls` itself is now dead! Nothing is pointing to it! So as `print` forces bits of the list, the bits it has already passed become dead.

In contrast, when you have

```
main =
  let ls = ...
  in print ls >> print ls
```

and you start executing, you start by calculating the thing to do first (`print ls`). You get

```
(printInteger y >> print ys) >> print ls
```

Everything is the same, except that the second part of the expression now points to `ls`. So even though the first part will be dropping pieces of the list as it goes, the second part will keep holding on to the beginning, keeping it all live.

#### Edit

Let me try explaining with something a little simpler than `IO`. Pretend that your program is an expression of type `[Int]`, and the job of the runtime system is to print each element on its own line. So we can write

```
countup m n = if m == n then [] else m : countup (m+1)
main = countup 0 1000
```

The runtime system holds a value representing everything that it should print. Let's call the "current value" `whatPrint`. The RTS needs to follow a process:

1. Set `whatPrint` to `main`.
2. Is `whatPrint` empty? If so, I'm done, and can exit the program. If not, it is a cons, `printNow : whatPrint'`.
3. Calculate `printNow` and print it.
4. Set `whatPrint` to `whatPrint'`
5. Go to step 1.

In this model, the "root set" for garbage collection is just `whatPrint`.

In a real program, we don't produce a list; we produce an `IO` action. But such an action is *also* a lazy data structure (conceptually). You can think of `>>=`, `return`, and each primitive `IO` operation as a constructor for `IO`. Think of it as

```
data IO :: * -> * where
  Return :: a -> IO a
  Bind :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b
  PrintInt :: Int -> IO ()
  ReadInt :: IO Int
  ...
```

The *initial value* of `whatShouldIDo` is `main`, but its value evolves over time. Only what it points to directly is in the root set. There is no magical analysis necessary.

Comment: So would you say that the difference in memory usage is happening because of something that the runtime does? Also, does your description require that the runtime know which values are mentioned in an expression? Or perhaps it's the compiler that does these optimizations?

Comment: @pdexter, and no, it doesn't actually have the expressions at runtime. But GHC compiles the program into a language for an abstract machine called the Spineless Tagless G-Machine that *essentially* does that. The STG code is then compiled down further in the code generation stage, and I don't know anything about how that works, but it gets rid of all the abstract stuff and makes machine code. But as I understand it, that's a *relatively* straightforward process, compared to other optimization processes.

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I've been looking for (assuming it's correct :)) So the compilation stage handles this and the GC is as naive as expected (meaning it's not getting any extra information, and the optimization is happening 100% at the compilation stage). I understand well what arrays actually are in Haskell and the basics of GC. I just wanted to know where this optimization takes place. As expected, the GC cannot know whether something is mentioned further in the expression unless the compiler feeds it information (which it sounds like it's not).

Comment: Can you type the STG bit up as an actual answer?

Comment: @pdexter, I don't really understand what you're saying. I know my explanation is a bit muddled; I'll try to explain it a bit better. If you want to know about STG, you'll have to read the paper about it. The essential problem with your understanding was the essential problem with mine until I sat down to work through it. From an "interpreter" perspective, the trick is to stop thinking about an expression as something that exists in its entirety until fully evaluated. That's an artifact of a simplistic representation. As an expression is reduced, parts of it can go away.

Comment: All the answers are describing why the garbage collector can collect it, and what lists are, and what garbage collection means. What I'm actually wondering is where this optimization takes place. Because it obviously cannot happen purely with that code and a GC. A GC cannot know what expressions come in the future, or what values are live in the coming part of an expression. I know of the STG and have skimmed the literature. If this optimization is happening because of what the Haskell compiles to on the STG then that is what I wanted to know. From here I will look at the STG output from GHC

Comment: More concretely: a GC cannot possibly know what values will be referenced in the future. So either (a) it is receiving extra information from the compiler or (b) the compiler itself is optimizing this (which is how it sounds). If the answer is (b), then maybe it is the phases of the compiler dealing with the STG?

Comment: @pdexter, I have tried to expand the explanation. I don't know if I succeeded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73440/discussion-between-pdexter-and-dfeuer).

Comment: @pdexter: Of course it can know what will be referenced in the future.  The whole program is a reference to a binary thing that can be executed and references to the variables captured in that operation.  The lambda \ x -> show x will not refer to anything except x and its show function.  The set of things that are referenced fall out of compilation naturally.

Comment: Yes, you can determine if they're referenced, however not if they're used or ever live. If I change this to a more complex example where ls might be referenced but not actually ever used, would the optimization still happen? The answer is yes. If I add a `if False then print ls else return ()` in the first example, `ls` is still and printed optimally in O(1) space. So it's referenced of course but not actually used, however it knows it can still GC it. This is most likely optimized away very trivially, however it's not just as trivial as seeing if it's referenced. As you can see

Comment: Or `f x = [1]` and then passing ls to it in `main`. These are somewhat trivial but of course the reference to `ls` is being optimized away in the compiler. So that probably answers my question, this stuff is handled 100% by the compiler

Comment: Also, I'm not saying it's impossible. I'm just asking what you mean by "Of course **it** can know": what is **it**? Is it the GC, is it the compiler? I'm just wondering where this happens, not whether it's possible (of course it is....). If it is the GC then it must be getting extra information, that is all I'm claiming.

Comment: The `if False then ...` goes away altogether if you enable optimization, so the runtime system (of which GC is a part) never sees it. The GC just scans things for pointers recursively. It does not keep track of any special known information about each thing, because that would take too much time and space. Each heap object is tagged with information that lets the GC see what is and what is not a pointer, and that's about all it cares about.

Comment: The `print ls` vs. `print ls >> print ls` difference would also happen in a simple interpreter, with no compilation/optimization. That's inherent to the basic evaluation model.

Comment: Then the answer is that the compiler does this, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

`ls` here is a **lazy list**, not an array. In practice, it's closer to a stream or generator in another language.

The reason the first code works fine is that it never actually has the whole list in memory. `ls` is defined lazily and then consume element-by-element by `print`. As `print` is going along, there are no other references to the beginning of `ls` so list items can be garbage collected immediately.

In theory, GHC *could* realize that it's more efficient to not store the list in memory between the two prints but instead recompute it. However, this is not always desirable—a lot of code is actually faster if things are only evaluated once—and, more importantly, would make the execution model even more confusing for programmers.

Comment: I know why there is less memory used in the first one. But how would a garbage collector know that there are no more references to `ls`? I'm wondering where exactly this information is observed and where it is used. The garbage collector itself cannot know this, it requires code analysis.

And yes, you are right about the recalculating business. It cannot know for certain which would be faster.

Comment: @pdexter The list is actually a linked list and the garbage collector keeps track of references to every node in that list.  So what happens in your first example is that every node is: (A) generated lazily (B) consumed by print, and then (C) garbage collected because that node is no longer needed.   In your second example, step (C) does not happen because the second `print` still has a reference to every node.

Comment: I understand everything up to the specific way that the garbage collector knows that, in the future, each node of `ls` is required. I'm not saying it's impossible, because obviously it happens. But what part of the compilation step is giving the garbage collector this "go-ahead" that it can be collected?

Comment: @pdexter: Garbage collectors keep track of pointers to memory regions at runtime. At certain points in the program, the GC pauses execution and checks to see which allocated blocks of memory have any active references. As far as I know, it doesn't rely on any especial compile-time analysis.

Comment: So during the print, it knows that it's the last line that references `ls` and so it can GC every node? Because `ls` doesn't go out of reference until after the `print` is called, after `main` is done executing, no? So how would it know?

Comment: For example, if you move the definition of `ls` to the top-level, I would assume that the same thing happens. So in that case there is still an active reference to `ls` even after the print in the first example (at least at the Haskell code level) however it would still optimize that away. So if the answer is that this optimization doesn't happen at the garbage collector at all then that is great. I'm just wondering where this optimization takes place

Comment: Remember that it keeps track of what references are actually in use at runtime, which does not have to correspond to the lexical source of the program. `print` consumes `ls` element by element and does not ever need to refer to a list item it has already processed, so the GC can collect *inside* `print`.

Comment: But in the second example can't you say the same thing? The print knows it itself doesn't have to refer to `ls` ever again. But there is another print right after it. That print of course has to refer to `ls` at least once.

So from these answers I'm thinking that this optimization must not happen at the garbage collector, that the GC isn't getting any extra information. So where is this optimization happening? I suppose somewhere in the liveness analysis? I'll look into this

Comment: No you can't. Sure, the first print stops having a reference to the beginning of the list as soon as it's done with the first element, but there is still an active reference in the program for the second one. When the GC runs, it can see this reference (at runtime) and knows that it can't collect the list's memory.

Comment: So it can see that it is referenced further in the program? Normally wouldn't a GC have to wait until it goes out of scope to safely collect it? Perhaps the code that this Haskell compiles to is more explicit about stuff like this? Normally GCs don't have access to future code, do they? If you were writing a Haskell interpreter that used GC, you could not safely garbage collect `ls` until the end of `main`. So, if this optimization is indeed happening at the GC level (which might not even be true) then it must either be getting some more info or just GC for the lower level language.